# Why can't C++ deduce a template type argument from a function pointer prototype individually but not as a pack?

Tags: c++, templates

This code compiles with both gcc and clang:

```
#define PACK //...

template <typename Result, typename PACK Args, typename Last>
auto g(Result (*f)(Args PACK, Last)) -> Result (*)(Args PACK)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Result (*)(Args PACK)>(f);
}

double af(char c, int i);

auto ag{g(&af)};
```

However, if I change the first line to:

```
#define PACK ...
```

Neither compiler will accept it.  The error says that template type argument detection failed.  Why can an individual type be detected, but not as a (degenerate) pack?

(Some background:  I'm working with an application that takes advantage of the fact that, using reinterpret cast, typical ABIs guarantee it's safe to assign a function address to a function pointer if the function's argument types are prefix of the argument types of the pointed to function type, and the return types match.  I was trying to write a template that would statically check for this condition.)

Comment: The template parameter pack must be the final parameter. Try change `g` to `auto g(Result (*f)(Last, Args PACK))`

Comment: You're right:  https://godbolt.org/z/7c35fo9Md .  I'm surprised, it doesn't seem like allowing the pack to come before the end would be that hard, as long as there is only one pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for the second case to work would be as shown below. Note how the order of `Last` and `Args...` is changed.

##### Method 1

```
//----------------------------------------------------vvvv--->OK: Last is deducible
template <typename Result, typename... Args, typename Last>
auto g(Result (*f)(Last, Args...)) -> Result (*)(Args...)
//-----------------------^^^^------------------------------>order changed here
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Result (*)(Args...)>(f);
}

int func(int, float, double, char, bool);

auto ptr = g(&func);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Mrxdf7oG)

---

##### Method 2

```
//---------------------------------vvvv--------------------->Last comes before Args though this is not necessary here as it is deducible as shown in method 1 above
template <typename Result,typename Last, typename... Args>
auto g(Result (*f)(Last, Args...)) -> Result (*)(Args...)
//-----------------------^^^^------------------------------>order changed here
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Result (*)(Args...)>(f);
}

int func(int, float, double, char, bool);

auto ptr = g(&func);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vYvqTY1da)

Answer (score 2):

As 康桓瑋 noted in a comment on the question, parameter packs are only permitted at the end of a function's formal parameter list.